# NiFi: LDAP Authentication Issue

Tags: ldap, apache-nifi

I installed NiFi 1.7.1 and NiFi ToolKit.

And, I try to add LDAP auth in NiFi.

But, I try to login NiFI login page, but it occurs error "
The supplied username and password are not valid."

login-identity-providers.xml :

```
<provider>
    <identifier>ldap-provider</identifier>
    <class>org.apache.nifi.ldap.LdapProvider</class>
    <property name="Authentication Strategy">SIMPLE</property>

    <property name="Manager DN">CN=admin,OU=NIFI,DC=evidnet,DC=com</property>
    <property name="Manager Password">passwd</property>

    <property name="TLS - Keystore"></property>
    <property name="TLS - Keystore Password"></property>
    <property name="TLS - Keystore Type"></property>
    <property name="TLS - Truststore"></property>
    <property name="TLS - Truststore Password"></property>
    <property name="TLS - Truststore Type"></property>
    <property name="TLS - Client Auth"></property>
    <property name="TLS - Protocol"></property>
    <property name="TLS - Shutdown Gracefully"></property>

    <property name="Referral Strategy">FOLLOW</property>
    <property name="Connect Timeout">10 secs</property>
    <property name="Read Timeout">10 secs</property>

    <property name="Url">ldap://myhost:389</property>
    <property name="User Search Base">OU=NIFI,DC=evidnet,DC=com</property>
    <property name="User Search Filter">(sAMAccountName={0})</property>

    <property name="Identity Strategy">USE_USERNAME</property>
    <property name="Authentication Expiration">12 hours</property>
</provider>
```

and, My LDAP Server table is:

[image]

Why does not it work?

I entered the correct password, but it does not work.

(id: admin, password: passwd)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your configured "User Search Filter" is referencing the entry's `sAMAccountName`. What is admin's `sAMAccountName`? Did you mean to reference the `cn` like your showing in the screenshot?

Comment: I changed sAMAccountName to cn={0}, it is successed! Thank you :)